# History for Mocha tests for react components

Tags: testing, reactjs, mocha.js, browser-history

I have started to write tests for my react components with Mocha. And when I started npm test I got an exception

```
Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM
```

I was tried to connect history object to test file:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react'
 import Modal from 'react-modal';
 import expect from 'expect'
 import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
 import {AdminPage} from '../../app/DOM/pages/AdminPanel'
 const history = require('history');
 const historyObj = history.createMemoryHistory();
 historyObj.createLocation('/admin');
```

But I'v got this exception again.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `createHistory()` in your tests, instead of `createMemoryHistory()`? The latter doesn't throw that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by the error, historyBrowser needs a DOM to work. You can simulate a DOM with a lib like `jsdom` to do so. Take a look to this tutorial for [testing React components with mocha and jsdom](http://jaketrent.com/post/testing-react-with-jsdom/)